# How to find the length of a string in one line in C programming?

Tags: c, string, string-length

Here is a small snipped of code.

```
int len(char *str)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(*str++)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

Now few days back I found a code which was able to this in one line. Basically there was some one line code in while's condition and that took care of finding the length of the string and returning it. It was dirty code? Yes, but it was interesting so I thought I would try to use it, but I can't seem to remember what it was exactly. So is there a way to do this in one line of code?

Edit:
Sorry for not mentioning the fact that no library calls like strlen. This function must be self-contained.

Comment: `size_t length = strlen(str);`.

Comment: Remove new lines and you can do it one line too! `int len(char*str){int count=0;while(*str++)count++;return count;}` Now you just need to figure out what you achieved with that. As it turns out, this only makes the code uglier - the resulting binary will be the same. _There is almost never any relation between lines of code and program efficiency_.

Comment: Better suited for code golf stack exchange.

Comment: Premise of this question seems impossible, as you cannot have `return` in `while` condition expression.

Comment: `return strchr(str, 0) - str;`

Comment: @Bob__ Would be nice, but you cannot have a declaration at that point, can you?

Comment: @DanielJour No, you can't, and even if you could, the compiler could not separate the following `while` from another id decl-part.

Comment: Please people, close this question already. It's unclear and too broad. And we don't need this many subpar `strlen` clones. Somebody might even think that it's good idea to use them!

Comment: _1:if (*str++ && ++count) goto _1;

Comment: Sorry to all, I should have explicitly stated that no library calls are required. But I do remember that I saw a youtube video which literally showed how to do it in one line without library calls. I just can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not want to use `strlen` and `for`, consider recursion.

E.g.:

```
int len(const char * s)
{
    return (*s) ? (1 + len(s+1)) : 0;
}
```

Explanation:

Ternary operator (`?:`) is used instead of `if` and if data reached with pointer `s` (the first letter) is not `\0` we count that character by `+1` to `len` of the rest of string.

Note:

Function fails when `s` point to nothing (i.e. `s == NULL`) or "string" is not zero-terminated.

Comment: Congratulations, you did not only manage to completely kill readability, but you also killed any hint of performance. Code doesn't get much worse than this.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I would have never written this in my program, but the question is.... and this is my answer

Comment: Well anyway, the amount of silly answers is a clear indication that this should be asked on Code Golf instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strlen(const char *s)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen)

---

Of course you could use the onliner:

```
int len(char*str){int count=0;while(*str++)count++;return count;}
```

But it will only work correctly **if your string is null terminated,** if it's not, you'll find some unexpected results...

Comment: obviously using another function is not what the OP asked for

Comment: @OhadEytan No, that's not obvious at all. Using `strlen` is the correct answer in real-world programming.

Comment: Not what was asked for, but the only real (= to be considered in any more or less serious code) option. +1

Comment: anything can be done with one-liner if that line is calling another function.

Comment: If it's not null-terminated, it's not a string.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub It's called specification. If your library documents that "this function will take a null-terminated string-..." and some low life tosses in a raw character array as parameter, the library is not obliged to deal with the error nor is it responsible for it.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: The OP is about the length of a **string**. A string is (in section 7.1.1 of the standard) *defined* as "null-terminated". You pass something not null-terminated to *any* of the standard library functions operating on strings (e.g. `strlen()`), you get undefined behaviour, and it's your fault, not the library's. Same goes for every single third-party library out there. Aside from that... let's say you get a non-terminated array as a parameter to your function. How *would* you go about determining that array's length? (Hint: You cannot.)

Answer (score 1):

The only real solution is to use `strlen`.

That said, how about:

```
char *s = str; while(*s++);
size_t l = (s - str) - 1;
```

I'm not putting it in one line because removing the line breaks isn't that difficult and the compiler doesn't care.

Comment: A nice solution, but, actually, 3 lines

Comment: @user694733 ops, thanks for pointing that out. Fixed.

Comment: @VolAnd Then remove the line breaks. A solution of "in one line" is completely pointless ... I can add a line break to make them need multiple lines.

Comment: Clearly this should be written as `char*s=str;while(*s)??<++*s,s++;%>ptrdiff_t l=*--s-+*str-1;`.